# The field of rational functions in $n$ variables is a Galois extension of the field of symmetric rational polynomials in $n$ variables.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, rational-functions

I've been doing a little bit of field theory for number fields but not much with function fields. The question originally asked says "For some field F, show that the field $F(u_1,\ldots, u_n)$ is a Galois extension of $F(s_1,\ldots,s_n)$ where the $s_i$ are the $i^{th}$ elementary symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables and show the Galois group is $S_n$."

Immediately I replaced $F(s_1,\ldots,s_n)$ with rational symmetric functions because of the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials. Then, it seems definitional almost that the Galois group is $S_n$ because I think the way symmetric polynomials are defined is by their invariance under the action of $S_n$ on the order of the variables. However I am confused about how to show this rigorously.

For now I feel like my biggest roadblock is understanding how to work with function fields. For number fields, I would make a formal polynomial like $X^2-2$ over the rationals and say this polynomial is irreducible and then adjoin $\sqrt{2}$ and this would be a Galois extension. It seems like if I were working with function fields of a single variable, $F(t)$ Galois extensions may look the same, $X^2-t$ and this would irreducible over the rational functions and I can adjoin $\sqrt{t}$ and this extension is Galois. But for function fields over several variables, does my formal polynomial have like several formal variables? Please help!

Comment: The question should not be "For some field $F$...", but rather "For every field $F$...". To answer your question at the end, your polynomial will have coefficients in the base field, whatever it happens to be (in your case, $F(s_1,\dots,s_n)$). Have you seen the theorem that if a finite group $G$ acts by automorphisms on a field $E$, then $E/E^G$ is Galois with Galois group $G$, where $E^G$ is the subfield of $E$ fixed pointwise by $G$?

Comment: So it's trivial? By your lemma, given a finite group $G$ of automorphisms on a field K, then K is a Galois extension of $K^G$ and $G$ is a the Galois group of $K/K^G$. Since the by the symmetric functions theorem that says every symmetric polynomial with coefficients in a ring can be written as a polynomial in the elementary symmetric functions, the field generated by the elementary symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables is precisely the symmetric rational functions in $n$ variables. Now let $S_n$ act on the field of rational functions of $n$ variables by permuting the variables.

Comment: The intermediate field fixed by this is trivially the symmetric rational functions. So the extension is clearly Galois with Galois group $S_n$.

Comment: If you grant the theorem on symmetric functions, then the result you ask is a simple consequence of that general result I mentioned from Galois theory. However, there is still something more going on here: the field $F(s_1,\dots,s_n)$ has transcendence degree $n$ over $F$, i.e., the polynomials $s_1,\dots,s_n$ are algebraically independent over $F$. So you could write $F(s_1,\dots,s_n)$ as $F(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ and the result you're asking about is showing that the "generic" polynomial $t^n - y_1t^{n-1} + ... \pm y_n$ has Galois group $S_n$ over $F(y_1,\dots,y_n)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Note:* Your polynomials are still polynomials in *one* variable. It's the *coefficients* of the polynomial that are rational functions in several variables, but these coefficients are *constants* of your field.

To show that $F(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ is Galois over $F(s_1,\ldots,s_n)$, it suffices to show that it is the splitting field of some separable polynomial with coefficients in $F(s_1,\ldots,s_n)$. Let $f(t)\in F(s_1,\ldots,s_n)[t]$ be the polynomial
$$f(t) = t^n - s_1t^{n-1} + s_2t^{n-2} + \cdots + (-1)^ns_n.$$
Since 
$$f(t) = (t-u_1)(t-u_2)\cdots(t-u_n),$$
it follows that $F(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ is indeed the splitting field of $f(t)$ over $F(s_1,\ldots,s_n)$.

Note also that $f(t)$ has no repeated roots, since the $u_i$ are pairwise distinct indeterminates, so $f(t)$ is separable. Thus, $F(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ is the splitting field of a separable polynomial over $F(s_1,\ldots,s_n)$, and so it is a Galois extension of $F(s_1,\ldots, s_n)$.

To finish off, we need to show the Galois group is precisely $S_n$. 
Note that $S_n$ acts on $F(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ by fixing $F$ and letting $\sigma$ map $u_i$ to $u_{\sigma(i)}$; these automorphisms leave $F(s_1,\ldots,s_n)$ fixed, and they are pairwise distinct, so this proves that $G=\mathrm{Gal}(F(u_1,\ldots,u_n)/F(s_1,\ldots,s_n))$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $S_n$. On the other hand, an element of $G$ is completely determined by what it does to $u_1,\ldots,u_n$, and it must map $u_i$ to a root of $f(t)$ above, hence elements of $G$ act as permutations of $u_1,\ldots,u_n$, showing that $G$ must be isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$. These two conclusions tell us that $G$ must in fact be isomorphic to $S_n$, as desired.

Another method is to note, as [KCd](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/619/kcd) remarks, that $S_n$ acts on $F(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$, hence, $F(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ is Galois over the fixed field of $S_n$, with Galois group $S_n$. The fixed field of $S_n$ under this action is precisely the field of symmetric rational functions, which by the Fundamental Therorem of symmetric functions is generated over $F$ by $s_1,\ldots,s_n$; that is, the fixed field is $F(s_1,\ldots,s_n)$, which shows that $F(u_1,\ldots,u_n)/F(s_1,\ldots,s_n)$ is Galois with Galois group $S_n$, as desired.

Comment: You could skip the first of this using KCd's theorem, right? Not that it's bad to have other reasons.

Comment: @Dylan: Yes, you are right. So I've added an alternative argument that does not require us to invoke that theorem, to go with the direct proof that the extension is Galois.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Thanks! I saw the alternative proof, but I couldn't see where to get a more thorough understanding of how the polynomials would actually work--for that, I am extra grateful!!